# Django: How to pass string name instead of foreign id when creating an object

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two table, **ShippingAddress** and **Invoice** table linked via `ForeignKey`. I have created a signals file that automatically creates **Invoice** instance whenever a new **ShippingAddress** instance is created.

My problem is, I can't directly add a new Invoice instance by using the string name rather than the ForeignKey id without getting an error

> "shipping_address": [
> "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
> ]

How do i go about using string name of the field `shipping_address` found in **Invoice** table while maintaining the relationship between the two tables.

**ShippingAddress** model

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_ship_address")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.name
```

**Invoice** model

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ship_address_name")
    invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=increment_invoice_number)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shipping_address.name
```

**signal** file

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ShippingAddress)
def create_invoice(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Invoice.objects.create(shipping_address=instance)
```

**views.py** file

```
class InvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

Comment: Kind of janky, but I'm more less asking on principal. Could you not use a manually constructed SQL query to get the primary key by name? assuming the names are unique.

Comment: i'm not getting you

Comment: I mean something along these lines:    cursor.execute("SELECT Id FROM ShippingAddresses WHERE Name = %s", shippingAddress.Name)

Comment: `shipping_address` is not a string, it is a foreign key field. Try printing the instance to see the value in your signal

Comment: @Lemayzeur i get it's not a string but a id. But that id refers to a string name found in the  **ShippingAddress** table

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a name field defined for shippingAddress. Did you edit it out by mistake?

Comment: By using a foreign key, Django automatically created an IntegerFIeld with "<table_name + _id> " .  Well, the foreign key takes the same type as the primary key of the model it links to. It is more recommended to use an integer as primary key for that table